# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get, node.js, apt

I've got an Ubuntu 16.04 server in production on which I wanted to install `node` and `npm`. So I ran this:

```
sudo apt install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
```

The [nodejs-legacy](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/nodejs-legacy) package is solely meant to have a symlink for legacy Node.js code requiring the node binary to be /usr/bin/node (not /usr/bin/nodejs as provided in Debian). I found I need it to make `node` and `npm` work properly on Ubuntu.

I've run the apt install command above many times on fresh Ubuntu 16.04 servers, but on this production server I got the following error:

```
$ sudo apt install nodejs nodejs-legacy npm
[sudo] password for kramer65:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
          Conflicts: npm
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Since this works on fresh Ubuntu servers, I have no idea why it doesn't work on this one.

I checked out my `sources.list`, but that only contains the following:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
```

Does anybody know how I can find out what's wrong here?

Comment: I use `aptitude` in such cases to find out what's wrong, and select a combination of packages that works.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-error)